# NullPointerException con el uso de la clase Graphics al adjuntar imágenes

Tags: java, java-swing, imagen, jframe, jpanel

Estoy creando un JFrame con un panel en java que muestra una serie de JButtons, JLabels y JTextFields por pantalla al usuario. Estos tres elementos que acabo de mencionar me funcionan perfectamente y ahora estoy intentando añadir imágenes y quiero para ello usar la clase `java.awt.Image`. He añadido la imagen en mi proyecto y la ruta.

Estoy ejecutando el código desde NetBeans. El problema es que NetBeans me obliga a inicializar la variable `g` (que es la variable de tipo `Graphics` que estoy usando) a un valor, así que le he asignado `null`. Al ejecutar el código me salta una `NullPointerException` así que creo que NetBeans no me está haciendo nada ya que mantiene el valor inicial de `g` que es `null`. Este es mi código:

```
package practica.pkgfinal.mtpa;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Panel extends JFrame{
    
    public void crearImagenes(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        try{
            Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("piedra_papel_tijeras.jpg"));
            g.drawImage(img, 20, 20, 90, 90, null);
            
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.toString();
        }
    }
    
    public Panel(){
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 300);
        setResizable(true);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        Font Arial = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 13);
        Font ArialBold = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
        Graphics g = null;
        
        JButton aceptar = new JButton();
        aceptar.setText("Aceptar");
        aceptar.setBounds(100, 200, 128, 30);
        panel.add(aceptar);
        
        /*Aquí hay unos cuantos JButtons, JLabels y JTextFields más que me funcionan bien*/
        /*...*/
        
        crearImagenes(g);
        this.add(panel);
    }
}
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para evitar la `NullPointerException` y que se muestre la imagen en mi JPanel?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: @MauricioContreras En base a la primera premisa de la respuesta más votada del link de esa pregunta, tengo que inicializar ```g``` a un valor no nulo. El problema es que no sé a que valor inicializar ```g``` porque no me manejo mucho con la clase ```Graphics```. Estoy haciendo mis primeros programas con inclusión de imágenes por ```java.awt.image``` y soy un novato en esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar esa excepción simplemente no deberías inicializar a `g` con `null`, de hecho tampoco se debería crear ese objeto `Graphics` ni llamar a `crearImagenes` en el constructor `Panel` porque perfectamente puedes redefinir el método `paintComponent` del `JPanel` asi:

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel() {
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    crearImagenes(g);
  }
};
```

De ese modo ya tienes el argumento `g` de `paintComponent` y a su vez lo entregas a `crearImagenes` para que haga su trabajo.

Adicionalmente el método `crearImagenes` no debería tener el `super.paintComponents`